# Garry's Mod Derma - HTML and containing

Tags: lua

I am having problems with my `Lua`. I an making a `MOTD` for my server using `HTML` that I am going to host with my website.

I have my frames set up and the according tabs, as seen

[image: here]

But this is my problem

[image: img]

As you exit the `MOTD` by pressing 'accept', the page set in the code stays up as seen and invades your screen like hell. My code is as follows:

```
function Welcome ()
    MainMenu = vgui.Create( "DFrame" )
    MainMenu:SetPos( 350, 100 )
    MainMenu:SetSize( 1200, 900 )
    MainMenu:SetTitle( "Welcome Menu" )
    MainMenu:SetBackgroundBlur( true )
    MainMenu:SetVisible( true )
    MainMenu:SetDraggable( true )
    MainMenu:ShowCloseButton( false )
    MainMenu:MakePopup()

    PropertySheet = vgui.Create( "DPropertySheet")
    PropertySheet:SetParent( MainMenu )
    PropertySheet:SetPos( 5, 30 )
    PropertySheet:SetSize( 1190, 820 )

    local DermaButton = vgui.Create( "DButton", DermaPanel )
    DermaButton:SetText( "Agree" )
    DermaButton:SetSize( 165, 30 )
    DermaButton:SetPos( 590, 860 )
    DermaButton:SetParent( MainMenu )

    DermaButton.DoClick = function()
        MainMenu:Close()
        RunConsoleCommand( "say", "I have read and agree with the rules")
    end

    local DermaButton = vgui.Create( "DButton", DermaPanel )
    DermaButton:SetText( "Disagree" )
    DermaButton:SetSize( 165, 30 )
    DermaButton:SetPos( 420, 860 )
    DermaButton:SetParent( MainMenu )

    DermaButton.DoClick = function()
        MainMenu:Close()
        surface.PlaySound( "buttons/button8.wav" )
        RunConsoleCommand( "say", "I disagree with the rules, I will now be disconnected.")
        RunConsoleCommand( "disconnect" )
    end

    local TabOne = vgui.Create( "DPanel" )
    TabOne:SetVisible( true )
    local HTML = vgui.Create("HTML")
    HTML:SetPos(50,50)
    HTML:SetSize(ScrW() - 100, ScrH() - 100)
    HTML:OpenURL("http://www.garrysmod.com")

    local TabThree = vgui.Create( "DPanel" )
    TabThree:SetVisible( true )

    local HTML = vgui.Create("HTML")
    HTML:SetPos(50,50)
    HTML:SetSize(ScrW() - 100, ScrH() - 100)
    HTML:OpenURL("http://www.garrysmod.com")

    local TabTwo = vgui.Create( "DPanel" )
    TabTwo:SetVisible( true )

    local HTML = vgui.Create("HTML")
    HTML:SetPos(50,50)
    HTML:SetSize(ScrW() - 100, ScrH() - 100)
    HTML:OpenURL("http://www.garrysmod.com")

    local TabFour = vgui.Create( "DPanel" )
    TabThree:SetVisible( true )

    local HTML = vgui.Create("HTML")
    HTML:SetPos(50,50)
    HTML:SetSize(ScrW() - 100, ScrH() - 100)
    HTML:OpenURL("http://www.garrysmod.com")

    local TabFive = vgui.Create( "DPanel" )
    TabThree:SetVisible( true )

    local HTML = vgui.Create("HTML")
    HTML:SetPos(50,50)
    HTML:SetSize(ScrW() - 100, ScrH() - 100)
    HTML:OpenURL("http://www.garrysmod.com")

    PropertySheet:AddSheet( "Home", TabOne, "gui/silkicons/heart",
        false, false, "Welcome to the server!" )

    PropertySheet:AddSheet( "Rules", TabTwo, "gui/silkicons/script",
        false, false, "Server rules!" )

    PropertySheet:AddSheet( "Group", TabThree, "gui/silkicons/group",
        false, false, "Group page!" )

    PropertySheet:AddSheet( "Ranks", TabFour, "gui/silkicons/flag_blue",
        false, false, "Ranks and donations!" )

    PropertySheet:AddSheet( "Admins", TabFive, "gui/silkicons/shield",
        false, false, "Your admin squad!" )
end

concommand.Add("OpenMotd", Welcome )
```

If you need to contact me fast, I can be found on Steam, under steamcommunity.com/id/PonyTerrance

Answer (score 1):

This is happening, because you are not closing the HTML object anywhere in the code.

Also remember, that you are creating multiple HTML objects with the same variable name - Either choose an unique variable name for each one or simply create one HTML object and remove the other code passages which are creating HTML objects.